# Intercept and alter sql query generated by the Application

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, handler, middleware

I have a situation where a plugin is querying and getting some data, I cannot change the query in plugin as its a DLL.
I have checked with the SQL profiler what query it is making and as per our requirement we have changed the database schema in that area, hence breaking that plugin query.

Is there any way to intercept the query and alter it?

Just like how we do in JS framework like Angular that we have interceptor to receive each call and add token in the header, do we have something like that to intercept all outgoing SQL calls and alter it?

Maybe middleware can work here as I am in .NET-Core or some kind of handler?

Comment: I doubting if this EF or EF Core. It's labeled as EF, but also ASP.NET Core

Comment: I assumed c#, is that correct?

Comment: There is far too much to assume here. Impossible to help you with based on this vague description.

Comment: @Julian Sorry for missing out those tags, I have added all appropriate tags, and have also seen your answer, thank you so much, I will check further.

Comment: Is my answer (below) not what you're looking for?

Comment: @Julian I think OP can't even get in touch with the context, but so far they don't show any useful details.

Comment: @Julian, it is only applicable for .net core 3.0, unfortunately, I am in  2.2 whereas we are anyways, planning to migrate to 3.1 and your answer serves my purpose, sorry for the late response.

Comment: EF core 3.1 works for .net core 2.2. I've updated my answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The query could be changed in a interceptor.

### EF 6

Implement `IDbCommandInterceptor`, for example:

```
class EFCommandInterceptor: IDbCommandInterceptor
{

    public void NonQueryExecuting(System.Data.Common.DbCommand command, DbCommandInterceptionContext<int> interceptionContext)
    {
        // Manipulate the command text, etc. here...
        command.CommandText += " OPTION (OPTIMIZE FOR UNKNOWN)";
    }

    ...
```

Register:

```
public class FE6CodeConfig : DbConfiguration
{
    public FE6CodeConfig()
    {
        this.AddInterceptor(new EFCommandInterceptor());
    }
}
```

See more details [here](https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/entityframework6/database-command-interception.aspx)

### EF Core

Also EF Core has interceptors [nowadays](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-3.0/#interception-of-database-operations). You need EF Core 3 or later.

While EF Core 3 needs .NET Standard 2.1 (so . NET Core 3 and later), EF Core 3.1 supports .NET Standard 2.0, so .NET Core 2 and . NET Framework 4.6.1+

Inherit of `DbCommandInterceptor`, e.g.

```
public class HintCommandInterceptor : DbCommandInterceptor
{
    public override InterceptionResult ReaderExecuting(
        DbCommand command,
        CommandEventData eventData,
        InterceptionResult result)
    {
        // Manipulate the command text, etc. here...
        command.CommandText += " OPTION (OPTIMIZE FOR UNKNOWN)";
        return result;
    }
}
```

Register:

```
services.AddDbContext(b => b
    .UseSqlServer(connectionString)
    .AddInterceptors(new HintCommandInterceptor())
```

Comment: please mark in EF Core area that it can only be used in Core 3.0 or above

Comment: I've updated the post to make things more clear about platform support.